# What do you call a break in rhyming in the middle of a book / poem for dramatic effect?

Tags: poetry, terminology, literary-device, nursery-rhyme

I'm creating a children's book for a school project. I've been tasked to identify some literary devices used throughout the book.

There is a section of the book which I want to highlight because it represents a major event. There's rhyming throughout the book. However, when the major event happens, the rhyming suddenly stops to produce a dramatic and eerie effect. I'm having trouble identifying what exactly this is.

What would you call that break in rhyming? Would it be considered a literary device?

> ...
>
> *They built houses and cities, what a marvellous sight.*
> *Oh how amazing it was, it just felt so right.*
>
> ---
>
> **Rhyming stops**
>
> ***But it all came down suddenly.***
> ***They had nothing left.***
> ***It all fell, like the trees they cut.***
>
> **Rhyming starts again**
>
> ---
>
> *Story continues and rhyming persists till end of book*

Comment: Since nobody else has answered, I would say that it would definitely be considered a literary device. I don't know a name for it.

Answer (score 3):

It is definitely a literary device.

The only name I can find for it is a "deviation" See [the paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/00437956.1965.11435425) "Internal and External Deviation in Poetry" by
Samuel R. Levin, which says:

> Thus, in a poem
> where a certain rhyme-scheme has been, or is being, established, the use of
> a non-rhyme would constitute an internal deviation. Such an occurrence,
> by frustrating our expectations, would call attention to itself and thus produce a stylistic effect.

To be more specific, that paper would classify this as an "internal deviation" because it differs from the rest of the poem.

Calling it a "break in rhyming," as you do in the OP, would be more specific and probably clearer.

Answer (score -1):

If those three lines were spoken in a completely different voice or manner, as if spoken by someone other than the person performing the rest of the poem, it might be called a "voice over":

> Voice-over is a production technique where a voice—that is not part of the narrative —is used in a radio, television production, filmmaking, theatre, or other presentations. The voice-over is read from a script and may be spoken by someone who appears elsewhere in the production or by a specialist voice talent.
> — [Voice-over - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice-over)

There's not enough context here to say for sure, but in this case, the person telling the story might suddenly stop, pause, directly face the audience and speak those lines in a normal, non-poetic, non-performing voice. Then another pause. Then back to the story.

Or, a completely different person might step in, stop the action, say the lines, and then allow the poem to resume.